# Alias for a route with a fixed parameter value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have this route:

```
Route::get('/MyModel/{id}', 'MyController@show');
```

The method `show()` accepts a parameter called `id` and I want to setup an alias for `/MyModel/1` so it's accesible from `/MyCustomURL`.

I already tried a few combinations, like:

```
Route::get('/MyCustomURL', ['uses' => 'MyController@show', 'id' => 1]);
```

But I keep getting *missing required argument* error for method `show()`.

Is there a clean way to achieve this in Laravel?

Comment: I recently discovered another way of setting up the routes, without annoying "@".
`Route::get('my-model/{id}', [MyController::class, 'show'])->name('show');`
it gives an option to my IDE to click-open MyController class from the router file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Laravel 5.4 (or maybe earlier) you can use [`defaults`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_defaults) function in your routes file.

Here is example:

```
Route::get('/alias', 'MyController@show')->defaults('id', 1);
```

In this case you don't need to add additional method in your controller.

Comment: It seems like this has been in Laravel since version 4.1. I'll try it out and if it works, I'll switch to this answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In same controller (in your case `MyController` ?) you should create one new method:

```
public function showAliased()
{
   return $this->show(1);
}
```

and now you can define your aliased route like so:

```
Route::get('/MyCustomURL', 'MyController@showAliased');
```

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this approach it's that I must setup a method for each alias. But it actually answers the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

define your route like this:
you can use "as" to give your route any name that you need.

```
Route::get('/MyModel/{id}' , [
        'as'=>'Camilo.model.show',
        'uses' => 'MyController@show' ,
    ]) ;
```

now if you want to access this route, you can generate url for it, based on its name like this:

```
route('Camilo.model.show', ['id' =>1]) ;
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for. This is simple redirecting to `/MyModel/1` and not an alias.

Answer (score -1):

```
Route::get('MyModel/{id}', 'MyController@show');
```

not

```
Route::get('/MyModel/{id}', 'MyController@show');
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the tip but what's the difference between having the backslash or not at the beginning of the route?

Comment: if that helped you , please accept the answer , for your question ; the diffirent is that thr first route is : localhost/yourproject/public/MyModel/5
for the second the route is : localhost/yourproject/public//MyModel/5
that's why your controller can't reat your id variable.