# Laravel fixed parameter value to controller from route

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.6

Can someone please tell me why it doesn't works? Returns nothing.

Route:

```
Route::get('/terms/privacy/', [
    'uses'=>'contentController@dynamic',
    'urlkey'=>'privacy'
])->name('privacy');
```

ContentController:

```
public function dynamic($urlkey){
  return $urlkey;
}
```

Comment: What is `urlkey` suposed to be?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825238/alias-for-a-route-with-a-fixed-parameter-value

Comment: use default `Route::get('/terms/privacy', ['uses'=>'contentController@dynamic'])->name('privacy')->default('urlkey', 'privacy');`

Comment: thanks a lot @rkj publish it as answer!

Comment: @Vixed i have added answer, glad it works happy coding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create fixed routes in Laravel that specifies the parameters from the controller method using [defaults](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_defaults). Like this

```
Route::get('/terms/privacy', ['uses'=>'contentController@dynamic'])->name('privacy')->defaults('urlkey', 'privacy');
```

You can look this

[Alias for a route with a fixed parameter value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825238/alias-for-a-route-with-a-fixed-parameter-value)

Answer (score 0):

You can define the default value to the function paramter.

```
Route::get('terms/privacy', function ($urlkey = 'YourValue') {
    return $urlkey;
});
//For Controller function 
public function functionName($urlkey = 'test'){
  return $urlkey;
}
```

And for the updated version you have default function also

```
Route::get('/terms/privacy', ['uses'=>'contentController@dynamic'])->name('privacy')->default('urlkey', 'privacy');
```